# Magento - Change the transactional email template used by a block in the CMS

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to add an additional contact form on my Magento website on a new CMS page. I'd like it to be different to the main contact form. I need it to use a different transactional email template. Here's what I've got so far, I just need to tell it to use a different template (probably in the `{{block}}` code in the CMS page.

On the CMS page I've added `{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/test.phtml"}}` to call a template block.

I've created the `contact/test.phtml` template file and copied my existing contact form template. I've manually added a field, it looks like this:

```
<li class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="armadillo"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('armadillo') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input name="armadillo" id="armadillo" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('armadillo') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've gone to the `System -> Transactional Emails` menu and created a new template based on the `Contact Us` template (called `armadilloTest`). The template content looks like this:

```
Name: {{var data.name}}
E-mail: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}
Armadillo: {{var data.armadillo}}

Comment: {{var data.comment}}
```

If I send an email from both forms now, they use the same transactional email template, and I don't get the armadillo field. It works, but I'd like one form to use the new template.

If I go to `System -> Configuration -> Contacts` I can change which email template my contact forms uses. I can set it to my new armadillo template, but again this is applied to both forms and my old contact form starts sending me emails with a blank armadillo field.

There must be a way of setting the transactional email template in the `{{block}}` line in the CMS, but I can't find out what it is! Can you help please?

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this...